# Read floats from tcp

Tags: c++, tcp, type-conversion

I'm trying to read big-endian 8 32-bit floats being passed from a packaged struct in a Python tcp streaming server. It seems to be close to working, but the first few values are off by an odd amount, and the later values seem off by a small amount, or just imprecise.

For example, these are values interpreted by the client:

```
Val[0] -1926.34
Val[1] -1936.86
Val[2] -1901.15
Val[3] -1935.93
Val[4] -148932
Val[5] -145905
Val[6] -41580.8
Val[7] -134330
```

And here are (close to but now quite) the values they're supposed to be. It's not quite the real ones because catching the exact same packet on the server and client is difficult.

```
Val[0] -7737.77159902711
Val[1] -7746.444075875769
Val[2] -7638.46279841218
Val[3] -7776.037785534595
Val[4] -148935.79768369172
Val[5] -145903.3365134402
Val[6] -41594.9200504923
Val[7] -134328.9103304041
```

Here is my code:

```
int size = 32;
char buffer[size];
float vals[8];
int count = 0;
int t;

// Receive a reply from the server
if (recv(sock, buffer, size, 0) < 0) {std::cout << "Receive failed..." << std::endl;}

for (int i = 0; count < 8; i += 4, count++) {
    t =
            (buffer[i+3])       +
            (buffer[i+2] << 8)  +
            (buffer[i+1] << 16) +
            (buffer[i]   << 24);

    vals[count] = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(&t);
}
```

The Python server sending the packet:

```
packer = struct.Struct('>%sf' % 8)
packed_data = packer.pack(*values)
sock.send(packed_data)
```

I have a feeling this could be an issue about conversion between the int and float but I can't seem to figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have access to it, it might be helpful if you could add the Python snippet that’s sending the data.

Comment: That's not a safe way to read data: your buffer may not be aligned sufficiently for the `*reinterpret_cast<float*>(&t)` access not to SIGBUS on some architectures.  It'd be better to `recv` directly into/over the `vals` array, using e.g. [`ntohl`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ntohl) et al for endian conversions if necessary.  Separately, TCP doesn't guarantee the same amount of data specified to a `send` call will arrive at once in a `recv` - you should be looping until you've read the expected number of bytes or encounter an error.

Comment: How would I use ntohl when writing directly to the vals array? It looks like ntohl takes an int which means I would have to convert to that first anyways.

Comment: using `|` is better than `+`

Comment: For a `float f`, you can use `ntohl` ala `(int32_t&)f = ntohl((int32_t&)f);`.  Do note that it breaks strict aliasing rules, so you may want to use a compiler option to prevent related optimisations.  (Separately, if you don't put `@` and someone's nickname in your comments, they may not be notified that you've written back to them... don't be surprised it people seem to be ignoring you - they probably think you're ignoring them ;-.)

Comment: You ignore the return value of `recv` (if it's greater than zero), so you have no idea how many bytes you received. How can you possibly operate sanely after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `buffer` is using `char`, which is likely signed on your system.

   If `buffer[0]` is `-1`, then that gets converted to `-1` as an `int` (no longer `char`). This causes issues when adding all these bytes together (because `-1` as a `char` is likely `0xff`, while as an `int` it's likely `0xffffffff`). In other words, if the buffer contains bytes with negative values, that'll screw up the "merging" of bytes due to integer promotion.
2. You're breaking strict aliasing rules with the reinterpret cast there. This will most likely work on any system you're likely to use, but strictly speaking is undefined behavior.

You could replace it with code that assigns the bytes directly to the `float`s, like this:

```
int size = 32;
char buffer[size];
float vals[8];
int count = 0;
int t;

// Receive a reply from the server
if (recv(sock, buffer, size, 0) < 0) {std::cout << "Receive failed..." << std::endl;}

for (int i = 0; count < 8; i += 4, count++) {
    char* ptr = (char*)(vals + count);
    // switch endianness as needed (though unlikely)
    // (this is effectively equivalent to std::memcpy(vals, buffer, size))
    ptr[0] = buffer[0];
    ptr[1] = buffer[1];
    ptr[2] = buffer[2];
    ptr[3] = buffer[3];
}
```

Even better (to avoid the unnecessary copying of memory), if you know the two machines use the same floating point formats and sizes, you can just do this all with the `recv`:

```
// read the bytes directly into the floats
recv(sock, vals, size, 0);
```

Comment: I'm unsure how to get around the error of casting a float* to a char*, but I need to use that method because I have to convert to little endian.

Comment: @jay: Sorry, I always forget which C++ casting style to use. Change the `static_cast` to a C-style cast (or whatever other type of C++-style cast it should really be).

Comment: My issue now, @cornstalks, is that I still need to use ntohl to convert the endianness. However I'm still not sure how to do this. I hate to ask for everything to be spelled out but could you add the ntohl function to this code? I've spent quite some time and just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: @jay: `ntohl` is for 4-byte (32-bit) integers. It's not made for floating point data types like `float`. `ntohl` doesn't make sense here.

Comment: so how are platform independent float conversions handled? @cornstalks

Comment: Very carefully. Usually people just use a pre-built serialization library [like Google's protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) to handle these details. Alternatively, if you're rolling your own solution, it comes down to carefully documenting what the bit-wise representation is on each platform (i.e. does each language use "little-endian" 32-bit IEEE-754 float?) and coming up with a safe way to translate between the two platforms. Thankfully, most consumer systems use the same representation, so a simple memcpy is usually sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using `char`s to do bit fiddling and this can be a problem on platforms where `char` is signed by default (most of them). Using unsigned char is better for this use.

Moreover you're not correctly implementing the read from a socket. The `recv` call is not guaranteed to get the amount of data you're requesting... in other word the size passed is only the **maximum** amount of that than can be read and the effectively received data could be less.

When reading from a socket you need to make a loop, quitting when all data has been received or when the result is negative or zero (negative meaning an error and zero meaning the other end has closed the endpoint and no more data is coming).

Answer (score 0):

```
char buffer[size];
...
t =
        (buffer[i+3])       +
        (buffer[i+2] << 8)  +
        (buffer[i+1] << 16) +
        (buffer[i]   << 24);
```

This is not the right way to byte-swap a 32 bit integer. What if `char` is signed? (That's the case if you're using Windows, linux, or OSX.)

The right way is to use the function/macro `ntohl`. While this is not part of the C or C++ standard, you will find it on any little endian system that is expected to work over the internet. On Unix machines, you need to `#include <arpa/inet.h>`. On Windows, you need to `#include <winsock2.h>`.

An alternative is not to inflict this pain on yourself. In a sense, this is all your own doing by using `packer = struct.Struct('>%sf' % 8)` in your python script. You apparently know the target will run on a little endian machine, so change the `>` in the `Struct` constructor to '<'. If you know the python script will run on the same machine as your C++ application, change the `>` to `@` or `=`.